# Why doesn't SDL_Mixer play my audio file?

Tags: c++, sdl2, visual-studio

I'm coding a game in SDL2 and I'm implementing the audio system using SDL_Mixer. However, my music file won't play during the program and I don't know why. How do I get the music to play?

Audio initialization:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
```

Opening the audio device:

```
if(Mix_OpenAudio(44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 2048) < 0)
    std::cout << "Error:" << Mix_GetError() << std::endl;
```

Loading the sound file:

```
Mix_Chunk *soundEffect = Mix_LoadWAV("Sound\BetaMusic.wav");
```

Playing the sound file:

```
Mix_PlayChannel(-1, soundEffect, -1);
```

Comment: Have you checked that the audio chunk loads correctly? Also, in general you should use the music-playing functionality that is provided by the library to play music. What happens if you change the path to "Sound/BetaMusic.wav"?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 the slash was the wrong way, I got confused considering it's usually \ as opposed to /, thanks for helping me, if you convert your comment into an answer I can mark it as the answer

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the backslash into a forward slash while loading the audio chunk. `Mix_Chunk *soundEffect = Mix_LoadWAV("Sound/BetaMusic.wav");` should do the trick.